# MySQL unique name for each index in table

Tags: mysql, unique

I have the following table, where id_A and id_B are primary keys

```
id_A   id_B  name
------------------
1       1    Bob
1       2    Jerry
2       1    Anna
```

I want to ensure that "name" is always unique for a given id_A, but I'm allowed to have duplicate names for different values of id_B.  So, for example, assuming the table values above

`id_A=3, id_B=1, name="Bob"` would be legal, but
`id_A=2, id_B=2, name="Anna"` would not.

Do I need to setup a secondary table to accomplish this?  I tried setting up a table which had id_A and name as primary keys and linked it to the original table.  However, this prevented me from updating either table individually since it complained that it failed a foreign key constraint.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't have two primary keys in one table. You don't need a second table, just a non-unique index on `id_B` if you're planning to use it in WHERE clauses.

Comment: The table that you ave showed would usually be a result of a join, and shouldn't be a table on its own. As it has already be pointed, there is only one primary key per table.

Comment: I'm not trying to have a second primary key in my table, I just need the combination of id_A+name to be unique.  You might ask why I don't use the combination of id_B+name as my primary key.  The reason is that I prefer to have a numeric primary key for speed of access and storage.  I have a linked table that has multiple entries for each combination of id_A and id_B and I prefer not to have repeated string vlaues in that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `UNIQUE` key over `id_A` and `name` i.e.

```
ALTER TABLE data ADD UNIQUE (id_A, name);
```

That will prevent inserting a duplicate `name` value for a given `id_A` value.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=20e65bbf3fecc1aada707e08a65943fe)

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly what I was looking for, but didn't realize it existed. (I'm still a relative MySQL noob).